# AngularJS Compile Breaks Negative Number Input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-input

I am trying to create a directive that will dynamically add attributes to a field. I got it working, but noticed there is an issue when it is used on number input fields. The input doesn't allow negative numbers.

```
app.directive("attributeDirective", ["$compile", function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 10000,
    scope: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.test.attributes.forEach(function (attribute) {
            element.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
        })
        element.removeAttr("attribute-directive");
        $compile(element[0])(scope);
    }
  };
}]);
```

it is used like

```
<div>Normal Input: <div><input type="number" ng-model="inputNum" attribute-directive/></div></div>
```

I created a plunker, that shows the issue. https://plnkr.co/edit/EocIbAGhIS5F5jDV2wGo?p=preview .

If you type a positive number into the "Normal Input", delete it, then try to add a negative sign, you are unable to do so.

If you type a positive number into the "Directive Input", delete it, then try to add a negative sign, you are unable to do so the first time. If you try adding a negative sign a second time, it works. But then if you type a number, the negative sign disappears.